# Move text down in table header

Tags: tables

how is it possible to move text a bit down from the top line such that it looks nice (see picture). My table text is to close to the top line.

Wanted table header:
[image: Nice_looking_table]
My table:

[image: My_image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\hline
Case & Re &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Mind Grid Spacing}& Total grid number & $\overline{C}$ \\

  &&$\frac{\Delta y}{D}$  & $\frac{\Delta y}{D}$ & $\frac{\Delta y}{D}$& \\
\hline
1 &150 &2  &   2  & 13.65 & $10^6$ & 12     \\

\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! (i) your codse fragment has error ... (ii) always provide complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. (iii) preambel should contain anly to your problem relevant package (iV) what miens `Re_D`? is this real value of `D`?

Comment: Instead of using `\hline`s you might consider using `booktabs`'s horizontal rules `\toprule` and `\midrule` that have a decent spacing around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the usage of `booktabs` and `multirow` you can achieve the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Case} & \multirow{2}{*}{Re} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Mind Grid Spacing}& \multirow{2}{*}{Total grid number} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\overline{C}$} \\

  &&$\frac{\Delta y}{D}$  & $\frac{\Delta y}{D}$ & $\frac{\Delta y}{D}$& \\
\midrule
1 &150 &2  &   2  & 13.65 & $10^6$ & 12     \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

beside use rules from the package `booktabs` you have at least three more options:

- change `arraystreatch` by `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}`
- add extra row height by `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` (or instead of the `2pt` a value according to your wish)
- use the macro `makegapedcells` from the package `makecell` (see example below, where also are used the package `siunitx` for aligning of  numbers in columns, however since context of table is not known, the selected `table-format` probably is not the best):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{lc
        *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]}
                cc}
\hline
        && \multicolumn{3}{c}{Mind Grid Spacing} &&     \\
    \cline{3-5}
Case    &  Re_D & {$\frac{\Delta y}{D}$}
                & {$\frac{\Delta y}{D}$}
                & {$\frac{\Delta y}{D}$}
        &   Total grid number   &   $\overline{C_D}$    \\
    \hline
1 & 150 & 2  & 2 & 13.65 & $10^6$ & 12                  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]